# Изменения в политике конфиденциальности

Tags: обсуждение

Коллеги, на «большом» SO обсуждаются изменения в политике конфиденциальности.

К моему сожалению (но не удивлению), эти важные изменения не были ни заранее представлены русскоязычному сообществу, ни переведены на русский язык. Я даже не знаю, релевантны ли эти изменения для ru.SO.

Обсуждение на [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370216/updates-to-privacy-policy-september-2021) упоминает довольно неприятные изменения, например:

> We will use your personal data in the following circumstances:
> ...
>
> - Where it is in our legitimate interests, including our commercial interests or a third party’s legitimate interest in using the personal information

— что означает «мы можем использовать вашу информацию, когда захотим, например на продажу (если только нас за это не засудят)».

Предлагаю обсудить изменения и их влияние на нас в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 12):

Обсудить, конечно, можно, но я вообще не вижу проблемы. Просто надо что-то привести в соответствие с законами, вот и переписывают.

Какие уж особые персональные данные я тут оставил? Email, ник и пачку ip-адресов? Да используйте - мне не жалко. Тут даже номера телефона нет.

Вообще, есть нюанс типа адреса и телефона, которые я отправлял Николасу для отправки подарков от SO, но во-первых, я не уверен, что к этим данным применимо условие про передачу ([спросил](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/370593/309650)), а во-вторых, это не касается 99+% пользователей.

Comment: Проблема для начала в том, что эти изменения никак не были согласованы с нами, и даже (!) не просто сообщены. Возможно, некоторых участников изменения не устраивают, и они бы в таком случае закрыли свой акк навсегда.

Comment: И изменения не выглядят как «приведение в соответствие с законом» (будут меньше собирать), а скорее как «ну сейчас начнём монетизировать покупку» (будут больше собирать).

Comment: @VladD, но ведь они это уже собирали.

Comment: А можно пруфы? А то в обсуждении говорят, что нет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130282/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-vladd).

Answer (score 4):

> К моему сожалению (но не удивлению), эти важные изменения не были ни заранее представлены русскоязычному сообществу, ни переведены на русский язык.

Они были представлены, в виде большой серой полосы в верхней части сайта. Любой, кто заходил на сайт в тот момент, должен был увидеть уведомление. То что не переведены, это серьезная недоработка, да.

> «мы можем использовать вашу информацию, когда захотим, например на продажу (если только нас за это не засудят)».

Это не ново. Старая версия также содержала пункт, который разрешал передавать информацию сторонним организациям в коммерческих целях: https://gist.github.com/pxeger/f00bae9440f0c8bc5d88c389c84b9e47/1ae210092e9866d3781b79aeccbe3d51637769cc#file-privacy_policy-txt-L94

> We may share personal information with third parties who provide services to Stack Overflow, such as payment processors, email delivery services, software providers, advertising providers and when we enter into product integrations with Software providers.

Не могут американские хайтех-корпорации без того, чтобы продавать данные рекламным фирмам, устойчивой бизнес-модели без этого не получается. У Google и других крупных компаний подобные пункты также есть.

> Предлагаю обсудить изменения и их влияние на нас в этом вопросе.

Я думаю, это влияние околонулевое.

Comment: не обязательно американских: [Яндекс](https://yandex.ru/legal/confidential/), раздел 7, конкретнее 7.2

Comment: @AntonMenshov голландские тоже, значит.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ :) агамся. Усе.

Comment: «Они были представлены, в виде большой серой полосы в верхней части сайта» — тогда, когда они УЖЕ были приняты и действовали, верно?

Comment: «Старая версия также содержала пункт, который разрешал передавать информацию сторонним организациям в коммерческих целях» — но дьявол кроется в деталях. Например, тому же самому термину могло быть дано другое определение.

Comment: «Я думаю, это влияние околонулевое» — да, я прекрасно отдаю себе отчёт в том, что наше влияние на изменения равно нулю. Поэтому я не предлагаю обсудить нужность изменений, и предложить улучшения. Я лишь предлагаю обсудить пост-фактум, что это для нас значит.

Comment: @VladD Уведомление было одновременно с опубликованием новых правил, насколько я помню. Уведомлять до опубликования они не обязаны, да и это бессмысленно. Они обязаны предупредить об изменения до того, как начинают осуществлять сбор персональных данных по новым правилам, но необязательно до опубликования новых правил. То есть здесь вроде всё как надо.

Comment: @VladD Ну я и думаю, что изменения ничего особенного для нас не значат. Они поменяли контактные данные в связи с выходом Британии из ЕС, и переформулировали зачем-то основной текст изменений. Но ничего нового по существу сбора персональных данных не изменилось, насколько я вижу.

Answer (score 2):

> Обсуждение на Meta.SE упоминает довольно неприятные изменения, например:

По этой части [ничего не изменилось](https://gist.github.com/pxeger/f00bae9440f0c8bc5d88c389c84b9e47/revisions). Этот пункт и раньше был.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что вообще изменилось по сути, а не просто по формулировкам? Только адрес представителя в ЕС, который переместился из Лондона в Амстердам?

Comment: Ну, вы точно уверены, что ничего не изменилось? Вы привели тоьлко фрагмент, а пользовательские соглашения, бывает, устроены похлеще стандарта C++. Я как-то не очень большой любитель отслеживать разницу в семантике в длинных английских текстах.

Comment: Например, что именно составляет legitimate interest? Может это поменялось. А может ещё что-то.

Comment: @VladD я в целом про то, что такие пункты там и раньше были. Формулировка может и поменялась, но мне уже абсолютно всё равно)

Answer (score -4):

**Пффффф** Ленин это описал ещё сто десять лет тому назад.

В частности на **примере буржуазного парламента , буржуазные корпорации ни чем от них не отличаются !**

***И так будет всегда ! пока цифровой пролетариат не осознает себя и свои цифровые интересы***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Что бы сделал я.
Если бы мог, просто у меня мало способностей, я цифровой инвалид.

**Тут я распишу как я бы сделал если бы не страдал цифровой "импотенцией":**

1. Создал социалистическую организацию, артель , хоть РФ и буржуазное государство но социалистические формы собственности в ней возможны.
2. Поднял бы похожий сайт, в принципе такие уже есть (https://toxu.ru/)
3. Стал бы воровать от сюда, туда все вопросы. Именно воровать ибо цифровой капиталист постоянно этим занимается, так что цифровой пролетарий имеет полное право себе это забрать. Как говорил Ленини **всё вокруг частное всё вокруг моё**

**Чего бы я точно не делал :**

1. Бодался бы с нынешней системой ибо потому что эта система так построена что люди в ней ничего не значат. Единственное на что она реагирует, на норму выработки прибыли.

*Быт формирует человека , это альфа и омега его существования, когда появится ресурс на других принципах появятся и люди для которых эти принципы будут основными*

Comment: Ну Владимир Ильич вроде бы предложил довольно радикальное решение проблемы (и даже взялся за реализацию). А бы вы что предложили? (Я имею в виду нашу ситуацию, а не Россию 1917 года.)

Comment: @VladD Расширил ответ :3

Comment: @VladD с Evg https://toxu.ru/u/Evg (поднял и одминит toxu) я общался с ним, классный парень. Отвечает на сетевые вопросы

Comment: То есть я правильно я понимаю, вы предлагаете ничего не делать и ожидать всяческих обманов?

Comment: @VladD я предлагаю : создать сайт в кооперации с людьми с таким же типом мышления , перетянуть вопросы , развивать сайт.

Comment: Понял, в общем-то тоже радикальное решение, спасибо!

Comment: @VladD как сказал один великий французский император глупому создателю парохода : "вы разведете огонь внутри корабля и он поплывёт ?? Сущая нелепица". Хотя в защиту императора , я думаю ему не особо пояснили смысл работы парового двигателя.